# Accept Field Value when Form is submitted with Dojo

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo

Small but boring issue:

We have an Form field inside an DojoX Grid (1.2). If the user changes the value inside this field, and is hitting the "Submit" Button without clicking somewhere else the new value is ignored.

Is there any way to "accept" all Values entered inside the field, when hitting submit? Or something like "onMouseOut" Accept value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An colleague has found an solution:

```
grid.edit.apply();
```

before submit..